# How to make AsyncMethod call generic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm trying to extract the token verification to a seperate method and after that the code block in the else statement I would likewise want to make generic.

```
public void Subscribe(string s1, string s2, string s3)
    {
        if (token == null || token.IsExpired)
        {                
            RestClient client = CreateRestClient();
            RestRequest treq = CreateTokenRequest();                

            client.ExecuteAsync(treq, (response) =>
            {
                CreateNewToken(response.Content);
                SubscribeToNotifications(s1, s2, s3);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var c = new RestClient(ServiceAddress);
            var r = new RestRequest("Subscribe?");
            r.AddParameter("P1", s1);
            r.AddParameter("P2", s2);
            r.AddParameter("P3", s3);
            r.AddHeader("Authorization", token.TokenString);
            c.ExecuteAsync(r, (response) =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    SubcribeCompleted(this, new GeneralEventArgs(true, string.Empty));
                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    SubcribeCompleted(this, new GeneralEventArgs(false, "Unauthorized!"));
                else
                    SubcribeCompleted(this, new GeneralEventArgs(false, "Error"));
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is how do I specify which method to call in the callback handler?
I have tried with `Func<>` but the other methods where I would use the generic token method do not necessarily has the same signature.

Thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: What do you mean by generic, do you mean using the generic methods that auto-fill .NET classes, or making your code more generic in that the callback method can be chosen by the caller, rather than embedded?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific - I want to make the code more generic in a way that the callback can be chosen by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action<RestResponse>` is the type of `RestClient.ExecuteAsync`.

`Func<>` is used when there is a return value, since there is none, `Action<>` is used.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how would you implement a the callback as being generic, meaning that what the callback is doing depend on who originally called the method?

Comment: Add an additional parameter to your method (after your three strings) of type `Action<RestResponse>`. Replace your lambda expression with that parameter by itself. For instance `c.ExecuteAsync(r, action);`. Then you would supply your lambda expression when you call `Subscribe`.